# How to push new local dependencies to shared hosting with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

My website is running smoothly with Laravel in a sub-domain, but now I have added a new dependency https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel to my local project using `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`.

The code is already working fine in my local environment, but now I need to push my new changes to the website.

Pushing the controllers, routes, views, etc it's easy, but how do I push the dependency?

- I have full access to the cPanel
- I can create SSH keys
- The project is running in a sub-domain
- I'm using Visual Studio Code
- I have generated a private and public key for SSH
- I have initially deployed my Laravel project to the server using FTP Filezilla

For what I have read so far, I should be using SSH with PuTTY, but if I could use an extension in Visual Studio Code, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can create SSH keys but don't have access to login with them. With that said I follow the tutorial here https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-and-shared-hosting-working-with-ftp-and-phpmyadmin/ that teaches how to use FTP to upload/update the application.

Answer (score 2):

Composer stores all the imported libraries in the `/vendor` folder. When you push your local copy of the website up, it will push up the vendor folder and you'll be set.

If you're working on a remote server and you need to still download the dependencies, run

```
php composer.phar update
```

That will download the dependencies for the project. You'll need to run it from the command line (ssh) and be in the website directory.

Some companies don't allow ssh access to the server. In that case, you can run `php composer.phar update` on your local machine, assuming you have a php runtime install (WAMP, XXAMP, ect). Then when you push or copy your code to your server, the libraries will be included.

Comment: if there isn't shell access OP can just upload the vendor folder from his local system.

Comment: @Tschallacka You are correct, I will update my answer

Comment: @ChadK your last paragraph, that means I have to always copy my entire project to the server? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Linesofcode that is only if you don't have ssh access.

Comment: @Tschallacka Well I can create SSH keys, but I tried to login through PuTTY and got the message: "Shell access is not enabled in your account". I tried to upload only the vendor/phpoffice but didn't work.

Comment: @Linesofcode the composer folder and the autoload.php also need to be uploaded. Usually theres a switch somewhere to enable ssh access or you need to contact customer support for manual release. I also suggest using git for windows. It has an excellent bash emulator with ssh support. If you have windows 10 install the linux subsystem for all the nifty tools there